# UILabels not updating immediately when triggered from a button push

Tags: ios, swift, label

I'm having my students do a basic button clicker "fighting" game where the player can press buttons to attack / defend / etc. and my students need to keep track of player and enemy health, and update the labels on the screen any time either changes.

We pretty much all handle this the same exact way... ctrl-click on a button and drag it to the code, in the pop-up window that pops up choose "action" which creates a function which executes when the player clicks the button.  Inside of that function change some HP and update the label associated with that HP.  Something like this...

```
@IBaction func playerAttacks {
enemyHP -= 30
enemyHPLabel.text = String(enemyHP)
}
```

9 student projects out of 10 this works consistently.  Every once in awhile though a student's project just won't work correctly at all.  Clicking the button will not update the label.  HOWEVER, using print statements I can see that it HAS updated, if I print out enemyHPLabel.text I get the new HP.  Yet, it's not updated on the simulator.

If they click again, it updates... but to the old value.  So in other words the 2nd click updates to the value that the 1st click should have updated to, the 3rd click updates to the value that the 2nd should have updated to, etc.  It's like it is always one click behind?

When researching this issue I've seen people talk about network code and making sure that you update labels in your "main" thread, but I'm not sure if that applies here?  We're not using any fancy code, this is really basic stuff. 
 Either way it is very confusing that it works for some students and doesn't work for others.

Strange piece of info, the few times we ran into this before the student had put their own image on the button, which changed it to a "custom" type.  Changing it back to "system" type fixed it.  However this student did not do that, and it is already on "system" type.

We're using XCode 9.2 on macOS High Sierra 10.13.2.  All of that is completely consistent between machines.

Any ideas?

/EDIT Attaching a link to the project if anyone wants to take a look: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1IXL6MsoQ4fv6VYRocFeyMmPOMGyu7kUp/view?usp=sharing

Comment: This sounds like a concurrency problem. Is there any chance that the "problem student" is trying to update the label from a background thread?

Comment: @Duncan C Not even totally sure what that means to be honest, but they created this function the same way the other students did, ctrl click and drag and pick "action".  It works fine for most other students.

Comment: @DuncanC `@IBAction`s are called on the main thread.

Comment: I attached a link to the student project if anyone wants to take a look.  I have no idea what is wrong.

Answer (score 0):

try:

```
 var enemyHP = 300;
@IBOutlet weak var enemyHPLabel: UILabel!
@IBAction func playerAttacks() {
    enemyHP -= 30
    DispatchQueue.main.async {
        self.enemyHPLabel.text = String(self.enemyHP)
    }
}
```

Comment: This just gives me an error: "Missing argument label 'execute:' in call".  And the "Fix it" gives me a different error: "Cannot invoke 'async' with an argument list of type '(execute: ())'

Comment: I've just edited and run the code above and it works as it should

Comment: It's not giving me an error message now with that code but it still isn't working correctly.

Answer (score 0):

Fixed it.

I looked at his next to other kid's projects and the big difference is that he removed the default title text for his buttons (he was placing "invisible" buttons on top of image views so clicking where the image was located would also click the button.)

Why this causes this weird issue I have no idea, but I just went back and forth with adding and removing text in the text field and testing both ways and it is definitely the issue.

Putting at least a space in the title text field for each button seems to fix it.  Or better yet would be getting rid of the image views and using the image field of the button.  ALTHOUGH... for anyone reading this who tries that, we've had a similar issue doing it that way as well, which only gets fixed by changing the button "type" field from "custom" (which is automatically selected when you add an image to the "image" field of a button) to "system".